# NuGet restore using 2 sources with and without http proxy

Tags: nuget, http-proxy, nuget-package-restore

In our company we are behind HTTP proxy, so we need to use it when accessing nuget.org to restore packages.

We also use an internal NuGet server where we publish some shared components packaged as NuGet.

When running CI build we want to restore packages from both sources. Is there any way to configure NuGet to use proxy for one but not the other?

- global nuget.org - using proxy
- internal NuGet server - not using proxy, directly

If I define a http_proxy in NuGet.config it's used for both sources, hence failing with the internal one.
If I don't define it, it fails with global source.

Comment: To help other SO folks add as answer, and mark it as a correct.

Comment: Thanks SilentTremor, will do. It's not an ideal solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up deliberately calling "nuget restore" twice, as a separate step in CI build before the main MsBuild for solution.

First call is for global source with proxy, second call - for local source without proxy.
It still complains on the first run about packages not found which live in local source, so I'm ignoring the exit code of the first run.

Here is the Windows batch code I've used in our CI build (in TeamCity):

```
set NUGET_PATH="%system.SolutionDirectory%\.nuget\NuGet.exe"
set NUGET_GLOBAL=https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
set NUGET_LOCAL=%teamcity.nuget.feed.server%

echo Restoring from global source with proxy
set http_proxy=%env.http_proxy_global%
%%NUGET_PATH%% restore "%system.SolutionDirectory%\%system.SolutionFile%" -NonInteractive -Source %%NUGET_GLOBAL%%
echo --- Finished with exit code: %%ERRORLEVEL%%

echo Restoring from local source without proxy
set http_proxy=
%%NUGET_PATH%% restore "%system.SolutionDirectory%\%system.SolutionFile%" -NonInteractive -Source %%NUGET_LOCAL%%
echo --- Finished with exit code: %%ERRORLEVEL%%

exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
```

Bear in mind, syntax here is specific to TeamCity, i.e. double percentage signs are used to enclose env vars, because single ones are to reference a TeamCity parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio you can do so,Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources

Comment: sorry it wasn't useful, I have not other clue how you can setup multiple package sources

Comment: what are you using to build project for  continuous integration?

Comment: nvm I've checked your profile, I guess you are using Jenkins, so I don't think is possible, maybe you can edit with power shell NuGet.config to restore from one source and then to restore from another.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing - runing "nuget.exe restore" twice, will post as Update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use **ProGet** as the only source of NuGet packages as it can mirror the NuGet.org package source locally.

Comment: Thank you Stecy. Yes, that could be the right way for someone. I'd still try to avoid adding one more tool to our zoo.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to avoid usage of http/https for the local repository at all.
You can configure `http_proxy` in NuGet.config for the public repo and add the company repo using a file path, such as `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\repo\packages` (if on same server) or any fileshare.